# Customizing Sharepoint OOB list views

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

Is there a way to hide New, Edit in grid View, Share, Power Apps, Automate options and keep only the Export to Excel button option in a SharePoint list view?

Answer (score 1):

Unfrothantly, there is no OOTB solution to control the list view toolbar functionality other than **Managing Permissions**.

So, I suggest sharing the list with **`can view`** permission would limit **some** toolbar functionality.

[image]

Otherwise, I think you have to use custom CSS.

Comment: How can we use custom CSS in modern page? How can we add the web part?

Comment: On the Modern page, you need to inject your custom CSS in SPFX extension, check [this](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/10/29/update-inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-application-extensions/) & [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-hide-command-bar-menu-item-using-spfx-extension/)

Answer (score 1):

The buttons "*Share*", "*Power Apps*", "*Automate*" and the Ellipsis menu will not hide even for View Only users (while keeping the functions).

You can use **SharePoint Framework (SPFx) Extension** to hide the buttons on toolbar, but of course that would apply to all users who have access to this list.

See an example here: [How To Hide Command Bar Menu Item Using SPFx Extension.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-hide-command-bar-menu-item-using-spfx-extension/)